# Xamarin Android Project Built in Xamarin Studio Builds in VS2015 But Deployment Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I keep having an issue over and over.  If I create a project in Xamarin Studio, build it and run it, all works fine.

Then I open same project in VS2015, I can build it and no errors show.  However, if I try to run it (or deploy it) to a device or emulator, it fails.

This is the information Visual Studio 2015 shows in Output window

```
1>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-09-30) or after any future revocation date.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\me\Desktop\work\xamarin\LocationTrackingService\LocationTrackingService\bin\Debug\com.user.learning.locationtrackingservice-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.user.learning.locationtrackingservice-Signed.apk" 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ENU7N16723000122 devices 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ENU7N16723000122 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ENU7N16723000122 shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist64 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ENU7N16723000122 shell pm dump com.user.learning.locationtrackingservice 
1>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
1>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.usere.learning.locationtrackingservice signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass91_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
1>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.user.learning.locationtrackingservice signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass91_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()<---
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I dont know why is this happening and how to resolve the issue.  My understanding is that a project created in Xamarin Studio can be opened and run in Visual Studio and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what the issue was.  Running adb devices listed my device and number of emulators none of which I was running ... strange.

Issuing

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

removed all the emulators and now only my device is listed as running

Next, I issued

```
adb uninstall "com.usere.learning.locationtrackingservice"
```

This made sure that previous version of my application was for sure uninstalled and has not somehow left some uninstalled files on device.

After this, I was able to deploy and run.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that worked for me, the steps are:

- Right Click on the Project Solution.
- Properties
- Configurations Properties
- Check the Deploy Checkbox option.
- Then Clean the Project Solution and then Rebuild it

It should fix the issue.